# SSIS Data Flow Task - It is illegal to call out while inside message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001005...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to learn SSIS and I keep running into crashing issues with Visual Studio 2017. Basically learning the easy concepts of importing Excel into a database and every now and again I'll run into this error. Basically what will happen is that one of the step symbols will have a yellow spinning circle instead of the green check mark and then I'll get the following error:

> It is illegal to call out while inside message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010005 (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_INEXTERNALCALL))

followed by the Visual Studio Delay Notification.

I can't click okay or close out - I have to end the task and reboot the program. Anyone ever run into this?

Answer (score 0):

### Many things to try

I didn't faced a similar issue before, but i can give some suggestions:

1. Try starting Visual studio in safe mode, since the problem may be caused by an extension, you can do this by using the following command from command prompt

   ```
    devenv.exe /safemode
   ```
2. Check that the Excel file is not corrupted, try creating the same package with a different excel file
3. Problem with the Microsoft Access Database Engine installed, try creating a similar package with a different file type (flat file) if it is executed without any problem, then check that the excel provider is installed correctly
4. Make sure that you have installed the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools

**Similar issue**

- [It is illegal to call out while inside message filter Acess 2007/Outlook](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/it-is-illegal-to-call-out-while-inside-message/c3a7f988-b081-4d98-815c-6f670e28464a)